# I cannot set default value on dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a constructor that passes in an IEnumerable of an object and then expose it from a public variable of type **SelectList**. In the cshtml file It has been mapped to a DropDownListFor and the dropdown populates fine, However when I try to attach "None selected" to the dropdown it doesn't display in the screen e.g.

constructor of the view model:

```
IEnumerable<Partner> beneficiaryNames
```

setting the value in the constructor:

```
BeneficiaryNames = new SelectList(beneficiaryNames, "Id", "Name");
```

declaration in viewmodel:

```
public SelectList BeneficiaryNames { get; set; }
```

then in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchRequest.BeneficiaryId, Model.BeneficiaryNames, "None selected")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the constructor of the view model I had to force a new object into the list. so I had to replace `BeneficiaryNames = new SelectList(beneficiaryNames, "Id", "Name");` with `List<Partner> newList = new List<Partner>() { new Partner { Id = 0, Name = "None Selected" } }; 
            newList.AddRange(beneficiaryNames);
            BeneficiaryNames = new SelectList(newList, "Id", "Name");`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a simple value type property to your view model to hold the selected value.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> beneficiaryNames  { set;get;}
  public int? BeneficiaryId { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your view, use this new property in `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
@model YourViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.BeneficiaryId,Model.beneficiaryNames,"None selected")
```

To select an item, set the BeneficiaryId value of your view model in your GET action. Assuming `beneficiaryNames` is a collection of Items with `Id` and `Name` property,

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vm = new YourViewModel();
  vm.beneficiaryNames= beneficiaryNames.Select(s=>new SelectListItem {
                            Value=s.Id.ToString(),
                            Text=s.Name }).ToList();
  vm.BeneficiaryId=2; // Will select the option with value 2, (Record with Id 2)
  return View(vm);
}
```